# Apache Tomcat 7 HTTP Connector node not found in intelliJ

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, intellij-idea

I am developing an application using GWT, Maven on Apache Tomcat 7 with intelliJ idea. i have recently debugged and run my application but faced the following problem:`Error running Tomcat 7: HTTP Connector node not found: set up one in the server.xml.`

Apache Tomcat run code:

```
"c:\program files (x86)\jetbrains\intellij idea 11.1.4\jre\jre\bin\java" -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\m2.conf -Dmaven.home=C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.1.1 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.1.1\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher --offline --no-plugin-registry --fail-fast --strict-checksums --update-snapshots -f D:\Projects\ebank\pom.xml package -P gwtDebug,oracle
[WARNING] Command line option -npr is deprecated and will be removed in future Maven versions.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AppFuse GWT Application 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.13 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 33 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- native2ascii-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:native2ascii (native2ascii-utf8) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] Includes: [ApplicationResources_zh*.properties, ApplicationResources_ko*.properties, displaytag_zh*.properties]
[INFO] Excludes: []
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (default) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 17 resources
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2ddl (default) @ AppfuseGWT >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 33 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2ddl (default) @ AppfuseGWT <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2ddl (default) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] skipping hibernate3 execution
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- dbunit-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:operation (test-compile) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] Skip operation: CLEAN_INSERT execution
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- dbunit-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:operation (test) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] Skip operation: CLEAN_INSERT execution
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:compile (gwtcompile) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] uz.eopc.webapp.MainModuleDebug is up to date. GWT compilation skipped
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) @ AppfuseGWT ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [AppfuseGWT] in [D:\Projects\ebank\target\AppfuseGWT-1.0]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [D:\Projects\ebank\src/main/resources/packaged] to [D:\Projects\ebank\target\AppfuseGWT-1.0]
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\Projects\ebank\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [279 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: D:\Projects\ebank\target\AppfuseGWT-1.0.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.405s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 09 10:54:04 UZT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/29M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Maven execution finished
```

What should be done to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to fix this problem. I was using ubuntu 12.04 and in linux systems everything is connected with permissions. After i have opened read and write permission to my tomcat directory, it has worked out. to open read and write permission to a directory in ubuntu just write:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 -R folder_name/
```